# How to stop webcam when using jpeg_camera javascript library?

Tags: javascript, webcam

I'm using jpeg_camera (with a ruby on rails app, irrelevant though) and I need to be able to stop the webcam streaming after I've uploaded the snapshot and moved on to something else (without reloading the page because I'm using turbo links).

So, using javascript on the page, how do I stop the web camera feed when using this utility?

https://github.com/amw/jpeg_camera

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't implemented yet, see this [merge request](https://github.com/amw/jpeg_camera/pull/11)